# New installations of Windows are not supported on iMac13,2 with 3TB hard disk drive?

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I have a 2012 iMac with a 3TB Fusion drive, currently with Catalina 10.15.4, and I understand I can't Boot Camp it, at least not with Boot Camp Assistant. I've assumed that I could do it manually, which stems from having started much earlier today attempting to make this work in High Sierra before updating to Catalina. I've run across issues all day no matter which direction I've turned in. I'd like to understand if there really is no way to install Windows 10, and if there isn't, what I'm doing wrong.

I was using the 
extensive guide at https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/. My current hurdle: when I go to install Windows, I'm told the it can't locate a drive or make a partition.

```
Darins-iMac:~ darin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Internal Drive          121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Internal Drive          53.2 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         1.8 TB     disk1s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data WINDOWSINST             1.1 TB     disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Untitled               +159.7 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 0256C1D9-2F56-4C25-8E34-E67E11D5F863
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.8 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk1s4
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled - Data         219.7 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 25.7 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.2 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      17.2 GB    disk3s4
   5:                APFS Volume Untitled                12.3 GB    disk3s5

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk4
   1:               Windows_NTFS FAT32                   15.5 GB    disk4s1



Darins-iMac:~ darin$ sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I'm not really familiar with this process and don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: An iMac13,2 is a iMac (27-inch, Late 2012). Why did you post a 2013 model?

Comment: 4:30 AM typo. Problem is still the same.

Comment: Are you installing on your Internal SSD or external drive? Make sure your computer supports the hardware requirements for Windows. Windows recogonizes SSDs even if they are HFS/APFS, they just need to be formatted to used. Make sure the partition you are installing on has a valid FS.

Comment: Internal SSD installation. As far as I'm aware, Windows 10 is perfectly possible on this machine, but apparently something about Mojave and beyond made this particular drive incompatible with Boot Camp Assistant. I've seen a few comments scattered across the web of people saying that it could be manually boot camped, but I've run into enough hurdles that I'm becoming less certain and I'm hoping someone has run into this or can spot the issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m in the same position.